# Can you charge a laptop battery with it out of the computer?

Tags: laptop, battery, ibook

I recently revived a 2002 iBook. I want to get it up and running but the DC in port is fried, thus making it impossible to charge the laptop battery. Is there a way to charge it externally? Keep in mind I'm not an electrical engineer, so a simple answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes, but "Keep in mind I'm not an electrical engineer" Might be a problem. Basically you'd need a charge controller of some sort that is designed for the appropriate battery chemistry and voltage, and any *internal* protection circuitry and such for the battery would need to recognise it. If its a 13 year old system, the batteries are probably going to need replacement anyway (Batteries noticeably start deteriorating at 3-4 years).

Fixing the 'fried' DC port would certainly be *simpler* depending on the manner of damage to the port, and many machines would simply run off DC anyway.

Comment: I have a picture of the DC in board, and when I received it it had soda residue all over it. I cleaned it up best I could, but the cables going out of the chip are crimped in place and covered by plastic, and I can't get in to clean them. That might be the problem? But i have no clue. If you want a picture of the board email me: apalumbo2001@gmail.com

Comment: Oh, that does sound bad. Death by fire is almost better. In that case the simple answer is "it would be difficult, unless you had another macbook around"

Comment: Hahaha, well, I'm working to get another one around. I originally got it from one of the elementary schools around here, and I'm trying to get another one.